# Delete from table using subquery from another table

Tags: sql, subquery, sql-delete

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odWIZ.png) I need to delete from the students table all students who got less than the average percentage of correct answers on the exam_results table. It has to be done using subqueries.

So far I've tried:

```
DELETE FROM students
WHERE id IN (SELECT student_id FROM exam_results WHERE percentage < AVG(percentage));
```

This returns: `ERROR 1111: Invalid use of group function`

Why is this an invalid use of group function?
What am I missing or is wrong with this?

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the student in `sub-query` as follows:

```
DELETE FROM students
 WHERE id IN 
   (SELECT student_id 
      FROM exam_results 
     WHERE percentage < (select AVG(percentage) from exam_results);
```

You can also use the `analytical function` but that depends on your MySql Version. so please tag the database and its version on which you are working.